# Can a jar file use the destination class?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

This is a java project in Eclipse.
Here's the example:
Project A with a class A.
Project B with a class B.
Steps:
 1. class A import class B so it can use class B property.
 2. make class A as a jar.
 3. put the jar into Project B.
 4. Project B uses class A of the jar.
But the Step 4 shows an error message: the import xxx cannot be resolved.

---

**Edit**:
For more details:
`A.class` in Project A:

```
import projectB.class.b;

public class A{
    String str = b.str;
}
```

At this time, there will show error as there's no such `projectB.class.b` exist in Project A.
But after making `A.class` as `A.jar` and put it into Project B, because there is `B.class`, so `A.class` of `A.jar` **should** work properly in Project B.
The problem is that I've tested it, but it cannot work.
It will show error: The import `projectB.class.b` cannot be resolved.
What should I do to make me can use that `A.class` in Project B instead of directly putting the `A.class` to Project B src folder.

Comment: If you want to use a class in B.jar ... then all you have to do is add B.jar to your classpath.

Comment: So you have a circular dependency between `class A` and `class B`, and the two classes are part of two different jar files?

Comment: @paulsm4 FYI, please check my new edit. Adding `A.jar` to project B is not working.

Comment: @AndreasFester Thanks for your comment. I guess this is not a circular dependency as just `A.class` needs `B.class`. And there is just one jar `A.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` imports class `B` (but `B` does not import `A`):

- put `B` into `A`'s classpath (as jar, or as project dependency)

If `A` imports class `B` *AND* `B` does import `A`:

- put `B` and `A` in the same project
- or (*better*) solve that circular dependency (i.e. by using an interface)

Comment: My problem would be the first situation. But as `B` includes `system.properties` and other jar files, I cannot or I do not want to put B as jar into A's class path. For project dependency, in project B, I added project A in java Build Path, but nothing happens and the error message still shows up.

Comment: Edit the classpath of project `A`, add a dependency to project `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse?
Just add project B to build path of project A
Prperties->BuildPath->Projects->ADD
Are you using Linux?
do the above steps manually by adding in build path of project A

I hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I am not familiar with project dependencies, I did what you said but the error message still shows up.